# Плохо работает функция расстановки кораблей (морской бой с++)

Tags: c++

Если поставить на одном краю поля(массива)один корабль а на противоположном пытаться поставить другой, то проверка "есть ли вокруг корабли" выдает ошибку. Ошибка получается потому что происходит выход за границу массива и переходи на начало следующего, где уже стоит корабль. По идее там стоит проверка на край поля, но она почему-то не срабатывает(выделено коментарием).Помогите.Кидаю за пример ФРАГМЕНТ установки 3 палубного

```
  if (((arr[x][y - 1] != 'O'&&arr[x + 1][y - 1] != 'O'&&arr[x + 2][y - 1]     != 'O') || y == 0) && /*((arr[x][y + 1] != 'O'&&arr[x + 1][y + 1] != 'O'&&arr[x     + 2][y + 1] != 'O') || y == 9)*/ &&
            ((arr[x - 1][y + 1] != 'O'&&arr[x - 1][y] != 'O'&&arr[x - 1][y - 1] != 'O') || x == 0) && ((arr[x + 3][y + 1] != 'O'&&arr[x + 3][y] != 'O'&&arr[x + 3][y - 1] != 'O') || x == 7) && x <= 7) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                arr[x + i][y] = 'O';
            pos = rand() % 2;
            f++;
            print(arr, comp);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "failed to set!\n";
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: если кто нибудь понел что есть, что нужно сделать и что написано, я его поздравляю

Comment: 1. Сформировать случайную точку х,у (начало корабля) <br/>2. Сформировать случайное направление dx, dy <br/>3. Длина корабля <br/>4. Цикл по Длине корабля {Проверить x+dx, y+dy в границах поля И не имеет смежных кораблей} <br/>5. Если цикл прошел успешно - выставляем корабль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все очень запутанно с проверками соседних кораблей и границ.
Лучше вынести эти проверки в отдельную функции, например :

```
//проверяем, что клетка в границах поля
bool in_border(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned size)
{
    if(x < 0 || x >= size ||
        y < 0 || y >= size)
        return false;

    return true;
}

//проверяем, что соседняя ячейка не мешает
template<unsigned size> 
bool check_cell_free(unsigned x, unsigned y, char (&arr)[size][size])
{
    if(!in_border(x,y, size))
        return true; //чтобы можно было разместить корабль вплотную к границе

    return (arr[x][y] == 'O') ? true : false;
}
```

где *size* - размерность массива(предполагается что поле квадратное).
Тогда проверка, что в выбранную клетку можно разместить корабль, будет выглядеть как-то так :

```
...
if(in_border(x,y) && arr[x][y] == 'O')
{
    if( check_cell_free(x,y+1, arr) && check_cell_free(x+1,y, arr) && 
        check_cell_free(x+1,y+1,arr) && ...)
        {
            // добавляем одиночный корабль
            arr[x][y] = 'X';
        }
}
...
```

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял как сделать проверку на то стоит ли он вплотную к границе.А то я получается ставлю его к правой границе, проверка вылазит за массив но попадает на следующую строчку где уже стоит корабль и все

Comment: @Sneikof, на функцию check_cell_free() внимательнее посмотрите : она возвращает true в случае, если вы пытаетесь проверить соседнюю клетку за границей, но к памяти за границей массива не обращается. Соответственно, если вы пытаетесь добавить свой корабль рядом с границей : 1) вы проверяете что находитесь внутри границы и клетка не занята; 2) вы проверяете все соседние клетки функцией check_cell_free(), - она вернет true для всех незанятых и для всех границ. 3) Если от всех соседних клеток вернулось true - можно ставить корабль.